# How to add a side group input using boostrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcQAQ.jpg)

I have three inputs and i need to add 4 small input boxes near to the third input box.Please check the image i have added

In the picture i have added 4 boxes.Exactly i need like this

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#form-row

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputName" class=" col-form-label"></label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputName" id="inputName" placeholder="">

            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputName" class="col-form-label"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputName" id="inputName" placeholder="">

            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputName" class=" col-form-label"></label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputName" id="inputName" placeholder="">

            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 align-self-end">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-1-12 col-form-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-1-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputName" id="inputName" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-1-12 col-form-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-1-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputName" id="inputName" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-1-12 col-form-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-1-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputName" id="inputName" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

try this code and don't forgot to add bootstrap libraries